# Comment peut-on traduire le mot anglais "Nullary" en français ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, terminologie

Je cherche à connaître la traduction du mot anglais nullary (fonction ne prenant aucun paramètre) en français.
Je sais qu'on traduit "unary" par "unaire", "binary" par "binaire", etc. mais je ne connais pas le mot pour 0-ary.

Est-ce que le mot nullaire est correct ?

Lien utile : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'ai trouvé les traductions suivantes:

- **0-aire**: par exemple,

  - "Une fonction 0-aire est une fonction ne prenant pas d’argument" ([Fonctions d’ordre supérieur en Scala](https://blog.engineering.publicissapient.fr/2012/03/02/fonctions-dordre-superieur-en-scala/)),
  - "symbole de fonction 0-aire" (J. Goubault-Larrecq: [Logique classique du premier ordre](http://www.lsv.fr/%7Egoubault/folf005.html));
- **zéro-aire**: par exemple,

  - "fonction zéro-aire", "opérateur zéro-aire" ([La composition des opérateurs](https://mabboux.pagesperso-orange.fr/Mathematique/combinaisonOperateurs.htm)),
  - "fonction zéro-aire, ou d'arité zéro" (J.-F. Perrot: [Introdution à Prolog, cours n° 1](https://pages.lip6.fr/Jean-Francois.Perrot/Prolog/Cours1.html));
- **nullaire**: par exemple,

  - "opération nullaire" ([Wikipédia: Algèbre unierselle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alg%C3%A8bre_universelle#Alg%C3%A8bres_2)),
  - "une fonction nullaire (sans paramètres)" ([Futures « maison »](https://h-deb.clg.qc.ca/Sujets/Client-Serveur/futures-maison.html)),
  - "une fonction de n'importe quelle arité (y compris nullaire)" ([Ramda](https://code.i-harness.com/fr/docs/ramda/index)).

Donc, apparemment, on a le choix et il est correct de dire "nullaire".